# Average of maximum among order statistic

Tags: statistics, expected-value, order-statistics

We have G groups. Each group has $M$ (i.i.d) variables $X_{g,1}$,...,$X_{g,M}$ following the exponential distribution exp(-$\mu$) ($\mu$ is a constant).

Focus on each group g (g=1,...,G), we take the $k$th ($k\leq M$ and fixed) order statistic $X_{g,sta}$, i.e., $X_{g,sta}$ is the $k$th-smallest value of each group. By taking the maximum of the G order statistics, we get a new varaible $X_{max}$=max{$X_{1,sta}, X_{2,sta},..., X_{G,sta}$}.

The question is: how to get the expectation E[$X_{max}$] of $X_{max}$?

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. First find the distribution of each $X_{i,sta}$. There is a result by Alfred Renyi that gives the distribution (see the Wikipedia article about order statistic). Then the maximum of these $X_{i,sta}$ is another order statistic. An exact expression is probably difficult. For large $M$, you might be able to use results about extreme value statistics.

Comment: Thanks. The exact distribution of each $X_{i,sta}$ is quite complicated. I hope to derive an exact result, is it possible?